# g++ std::bind error with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, bind, shared-ptr

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code does not compile.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class Foo 
{
public:
  void Bar(int i) {}
};

void X(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)> f)
{

}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> f(new Foo);
  auto f1(std::bind(&Foo::Bar, std::placeholders::_1, 1));
  X(f1);
  return 0;
}
```

g++ (4.6.3) outputs...

```
n file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/memory:80:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In static member function ‘static void std::_Function_handler<void(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>(std::_Placeholder<1>, int)>, _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<Foo>}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:2148:6:   instantiated from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>(std::_Placeholder<1>, int)>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<Foo>}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)>::_Useless]’
test.cpp:19:7:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1778:2: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>(std::_Placeholder<1>, int)>) (std::shared_ptr<Foo>)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1130:11: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1201:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>, _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, int}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1215:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>, _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, int}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1229:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>, _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, int}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1243:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(int)>, _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, int}]
```

Comment: Try `std::bind(&Foo::Bar,f.get(),1);` I think that should evaluate to Bar(1)

Comment: @user814628, how does that help pass `f1` to `X`?

Answer (score 5):

It's a GCC bug, which I fixed in 4.7, but I don't remember exactly which bug. I'll try to figure it out ...

**Edit:** Aha, it's [PR 55463](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55463) so isn't fixed in 4.7, it's only fixed on GCC trunk (what will be 4.8)

The bug was that the call wrapper returned by `mem_fn` doesn't accept rvalues, and your `std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)` type passes an rvalue `shared_ptr<Foo>` to the call wrapper return by `bind`.

As a workaround you can change your function signature to this:

```
void X(std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>&)> f)
```

I don't think I can backport the fix to the 4.7 branch, because as a result of that bug I made some quite large changes to `mem_fn` that aren't really suitable for a stable release branch (I also found a new [defect](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219) in the standard)